# How do I keep this 2d dynamic array program from crashing?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, 2d, allocation

ok. so this program is supposed to read in an unknown number of names at unknown lengths and is supposed to stop reading names once the user hits the enter key on a blank line. everywhere that i look, somebody says to use vectors. however, this is for an assignment that specifically requires a dynamic array. as of right now, the program will read the first name just fine and then when you enter the second name, it will crash. does it have something to do with how i am initiating/allocating the array? any help would be greatly appreciated as this thing has been plaguing me for days.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    long numnames=0
    long namelength=0;
    char ** pNames;
    pNames = new char* [numnames];
    pNames [numnames] = new char [namelength];
    char c;
    bool cont=true;

while(cont)
{
    while ((c=cin.get())!='\n') // input loop
    {
        pNames [numnames] [namelength++]=(c);
    }

    pNames[numnames] [namelength]='\0'; // end of string mark
    if(c='\n' && namelength==0) //if enter is pressed on an empty line, stop reading names
        cont=false;
    else
    {
        numnames++;
        namelength=0;
    }   
}
cout<<pNames<<endl; // used as a progress marker

for(int i=0; i<=numnames; i++) // mem clear loop
    delete [] pNames [i];
delete [] pNames;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're allocating space for 0 strings of 0 characters each.

Comment: The answer to near-*all* "how to stop this from crashing" questions is: Don't invoke undefined behavior. For an example of said invocation, see chris' comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you're trying to change the size of the array by changing the value 'numnames'

If you set the size of an array to a variable, it will **not** change the size of the array when the variable is changed. You have two options: copy the contents of the array, reallocate the array, and move back the contents, or you can create a new array with a new size and copy over the elements.

I am going to be demonstrating the second way. Do note that this is pseudo-code, which means it shouldn't be used directly. The array will be of the type 'int'. You'll have to implement this code yourself.

```
// This function resizes an int array 'array'
// of size 'size' to the size of 'newSize'
void resize(int size, int newSize, int* array)
{
    // The array of the new size
    int* newArray = new int[newSize];

    // 'memcpy' copies over the elements of one array to another.
    // The first argument is the array to copy to.
    // The second argument is the array to copy from.
    // The third argument is the size of the array in the second argument.
    memcpy(newArray, array, size * sizeof(int));

    // Deallocates the old array so we can safely make it point to the new array.
    delete[] array;

    // Since the old array is deallocated, we can make it point to the address of
    // the new array without it becoming a memory leak.
    array = newArray;

    // The original array's size has now been changed, and you can
    // safely change it's values normally after it's been resized.
}
```

Remember to read this one, and understand it. If you can't understand this, then I'd recommend you to read up more on pointers and dynamic arrays. Once you understand, rewrite it to fit your needs.

I'd also highly recommend creating a templated class for the dynamic array. It will just make it so much more convenient, and it should avoid any memory leaks due to a exception.
If you don't know what I am talking about now either, I'd recommend you to read up more on templates.

(By the way, I can't guarantee with a 100% certainty this will work. I didn't have the time to test it)

Comment: there are 3 news and 1 delete so something leaks.

Comment: That's true. And I guess you could also replace the initial copying with a 'memcpy' to be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you **@Sirolu**. I greatly appreciate your help and thorough explanation.